# Angularfire angular Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

When trying to edit/update, I get this error message below. What does this error mean?

I changed paths and instead of `$key` I put `id`, but error still occurs. Any help would be appreciated.

> "EditBookComponent.html:52 ERROR Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "books/[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
>       "
>       "

```
// TODO = Perf = Consider combining the recursive validation of keys into NodeFromJSON
    // to save extra walking of large objects.
    if (data && (typeof data === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(data)) === 'object') {
        var hasDotValue_1 = false,
            hasActualChild_1 = false;
        (0, _obj.forEach)(data, function (key, value) {
            if (key === '.value') {
                hasDotValue_1 = true;
            } else if (key !== '.priority' && key !== '.sv') {
                hasActualChild_1 = true;
                if (!isValidKey(key)) {
                    throw new Error(errorPrefix + ' contains an invalid key (' + key + ') ' + path.toErrorString() + '.  Keys must be non-empty strings ' + 'and can\'t contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"');
                }
```

### UPDATE

here is the code. PushUpload and updateBooklet functions.

in the service.ts:

```
pushUpload(upload: Upload) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

  const sub = uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) =>  {
      // upload in progress
      const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot
      upload.progress = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
    },
    (error) => {
      // upload failed
      console.log(error)
    },
    ():any => {
      // upload success
      upload.imageUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
      upload.name = upload.file.name
      // this.saveFileData(upload)
      return upload.file.name
    }
  );

  return uploadTask.then(snap => this.saveFileData(upload).key)
}


// Writes the file details to the realtime db
private saveFileData(upload: Upload) {
  return this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(upload);
}


updateBooklet(book, id){
     return this.db.object('books/'+ id).update(book);
   }


in the routes I put this:

const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'book-list', component:BookListComponent},
  {path:'book-details/:id', component:BookDetailsComponent},
  {path:'add-book', component:AddBookComponent},
  {path:'edit-book/:id', component:EditBookComponent}
```

Comment: This error is self explanatory : "First argument was an invalid path = "books/[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"".
You are passing object ([object Object]) which is invalid in this case, but please update your question with code sample, not only error message.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:slUhJm9ddvMJ:https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

Comment: I followed your steps how to debug and rechecked the object and didnt find any (.keys or strange value). Any real assistance would be appreciated.